# Using Gnosis safe as a multisig owner to ERC20 token contract

Tags: erc-20, gnosis-safe, multisignature, safe

I launched a wallet and created a safe on the safe website with 3 owners and 2/3 threshold. Now i have an erc20 token contract which is ownable. I have some functions in erc20 token contract which are onlyOwner access controlled.

Now i want to make the safe contract as the owner and for onlyOwner function i want to have the threshold required to run it i.e i would need threshold signatures to call mint and burn functions .

How do i do that? Is it even possible?  Since safe is implemented using proxy , do i make the proxy address as the owner or the implementation ?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is possible.
First, you must use the proxy address of your multisig wallet.

> How do you find this?

Use the grantRole function of your erc-20 token with this address.

> How can I do this in Remix? It doesn't seem to be a function available for OpenZepplin ERC20 tokens...

Next, just make a propos from one of the owners of the wallet for a mint, confirm the action from 2 owners and complete it.
I can give detailed advice in a personal.
Write to:is5201@mail.ru

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do something like this. Most likely a cleaner way to do it, but I think this would do the job if I am understanding correctly.

```js
    contract MultiSigExample {
        struct Signers {
            address[] signers;
        }

        Signers public signers;

        //Minimum number of signatures to authorize a multisig authorized function.
        uint public constant multiSigThreshold = 2;
        
        //Mapping of signer -> function signature -> signed.
        mapping(address => mapping(bytes4 => bool)) multiSig;
        mapping(address => bool) isSigner;
        
        //Ensures msg.sig has two signatures from authorized signers.
        modifier onlyMultiSig() {
           bytes4 memory fSig = msg.sig;
           address[] memory signers = Signers.signers;
           uint signatures = 0;
           for (uint i=0; i<signers.length()-1;){
               if (multiSig[signers[i][fSig]){
                  signatures++;
                  
                  if signatures >= multiSigThreshold {
                      break;
                  }
               }
               unchecked {
                   ++i;
               }
           }
           require(signatures >= multiSigThreshold, "Unauthorized function call"); 
           //Reset the signature status to false for reusability.
           for(uint i=0; i<=signatures;){
               multiSig[signers[i]][fSig] = false;
               unchecked {
                   ++i;
               }
           }
           
           _;
        }

        //Require msg.sender is an authorized signer.
        modifier onlySigner() {
            require(isSigner[msg.sender], "Unauthorized Signer");
            _;
        }
        
        constructor(address[] memory _signers) {
             signers = Signers({signers: _signers});
             for signer in _signers {
                 isSigner[_signer] = true;
             }
        }
        
        //Function to authorize fSig from a specific account.
        function sign(bytes4 memory fSig) public onlySigner {
            multiSig[msg.sender][fSig] = true;
        }
        
        //Only callable after two signatures from the signers.
        function mint() external onlySigner onlyMultiSig {
            
        }

        //Only callable after two signatures from the signers.
        function burn() external onlySigner onlyMultiSig {

        }
    
    }
```